# Estimation of the difference of two integrals

Tags: calculus

My goal is to find an estimate for the following difference of integrals.
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{(\sinh t)^{(2n)}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1}dt-\int_0^{\alpha x}\frac{(\cosh t)^{(2n-1)}}{(2n-2)!}(\alpha x-t)^{2n-2}dt$$

with $0\leq\alpha\leq1$ (real parameter) and $x\in \mathbb R$. The difference is in reality a difference of integrals remains in the Taylor series, but I do not think this is very important.

I thought that, for $0\leq\alpha x\leq x$ we have

$$\int_0^{\alpha x} \left( \frac{1}{x}\frac{(\sinh t)^{(2n)}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1}-\frac{(\cosh t)^{(2n-1)}}{(2n-2)!}(\alpha x-t)^{2n-2}\right)dt+\\
\frac{1}{x}\int_{\alpha x}^x\frac{(\sinh t)^{(2n)}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1}dt$$

but I can not go on. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is the $2n$ a power or derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really specified what kind of estimate you want, or what quality/precision you need. I'll provide a rough, non-rigourous, estimate (suitable for putting up shelves, not for putting a man on the moon). I'm going to assume $ x > 0$ otherwise repeat the below with symmetry arguments.

Firstly, $\sinh$ is odd, but to an even power, it is also monotone on $[0, \infty)$. Therefore maximum of $(\sinh t)^{2n}$ is $(\sinh x)^{2n}$. The term $(x-t)^{2n-1}$ is monotone decreasing in $t$ hence it's maximum value is $x^{2n-1}$.

Therefore,

$\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{(\sinh t)^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1}dt \leq \frac{1}{x} \cdot x \cdot \sup_{t \in [0,x]} \frac{(\sinh t)^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1} = \frac{(\sinh x)^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}$

To estimate the cosine term,

$\int_0^{\alpha x} \frac{(\cosh t)^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!}(x-t)^{2n-2}dt \geq  {\alpha x} \cdot \inf_{t \in [0,\alpha x]} \frac{(\cosh t)^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!}(x-t)^{2n-2} = \frac{(\cosh 0)^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!}x^{2n-2} = \frac{1}{(2n-2)!}x^{2n-2}$

using similar monotonicity considerations. Therefore,

$\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{(\sinh t)^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}(x-t)^{2n-1}dt - \int_0^{\alpha x} \frac{(\cosh t)^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!}(x-t)^{2n-2}dt \leq \frac{(\sinh x)^{2n}}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1} - \frac{1}{(2n-2)!}x^{2n-2}$.

An estimate below can be derived similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Right dcs24. Mark, you may take a look for some research papers about this subject:

[http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0898-1221(03)90037-X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0898-1221%2803%2990037-X)

http://rgmia.org/papers/v16/v16a11.pdf

and others (google it)